# What is the joint density function of two dependent standard Normal random variables, i.e., $X+Y = 0$?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability, order-statistics

If we know the marginal PDFs of two standard Normal random variables X and Y, then what is the joint PDF of $X + Y = 0$ or, $X = - Y$? Will it be a degenerate PDF in this case? Any help to derive the expression will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Joint density of $X,Y$ does not exist.

Comment: Well, I know that the joint PDF is a degenerate PDF, but how can we analytically show it in terms of the given condition $X+Y = 0$?

Comment: Lebesgue measure of $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}: y=-x\}=0$.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does 'joint PDF of $X+Y=0$' mean? If you are asking about the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ when $X+Y=0$, or equivalently, joint pdf of $(X,-X)$, then that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why I mentioned $X = -Y$. Thanks.